# Left matrix divide with vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, solver, backslash

How explicitly does Matlab solve the rightmost equation in `c1`, specifically `((x-1)\y)`?

I am well aware what happens when you use a matrix, e.g. A\b (where A is a matrix and b is a column vector), but what happens when you use backslash on two vectors with equal rows?

The problem:

```
x = (1:3)';
y = ones(3,1);
c1 = ((x-1)\y) % why does this =0.6?
```

Comment: I think [the documetstion](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) is very clear. Just think of an N-vector as an N-by-1 matrix.

Comment: I don't fully see it. Are there any mathematic equations or steps that you could provide, to clarify how the answer equals 0,6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing `[0;1;2]\[1;1;1]`. Essentially `x=0.6` is the least-squares solution to

```
[0;1;2]*x=[1;1;1]
```

The case you have from the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) is the following:

> If A is a rectangular m-by-n matrix with m ~= n, and B is a matrix with m rows, then **A\B returns a least-squares solution to the system of equations A*x= B**.

(Specifically, you have `m=3, n=1`).

```
A = (1:3).' - 1; % = [0;1;2]
B = ones(3,1);   % = [1;1;1]

x = A\B; % = 0.6
```

Algebraically, it's easy to see this is the solution to the least-squares minimisation

```
% Calculate least squares
leastSquares = sum( ((A*x) - B).^2 )
             = sum( ([0;1;2]*x - [1;1;1]).^2 )
             = sum( [-1; x-1; 2x-1].^2 )
             = 1 + (x-1)^2 + (2x-1)^2
             = 1 + x^2 - 2*x + 1 + 4*x^2 - 4*x + 1
             = 5*x^2 - 6*x + 3
% Minimum least squares -> derivative = 0
d(leastSquares)/dx = 10*x - 6 = 0
              10*x = 6
                 x = 0.6
```

**I have no doubt that MATLAB uses a more sophisticated algorithm** to come to the same conclusion, but this lays out the mathematics in a fairly plain way.

---

You can see experimentally that there is no better solution by testing the following for various values of `x`... 0.6 gives the smallest error:

```
sum( ([0;1;2]*x - [1;1;1]).^2 )
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Also: `x = linspace(0,1,200); plot(x, sum( ([0;1;2]*x - [1;1;1]).^2 ))`

Comment: Thanks @Cris, that's a nice way to show the final thought graphically.